# CRXDE lite: AEM 6.2 Canot find folder "forms" in /content

Tags: forms, aem

Is there a way to get information of when/who has deleted "forms" folder that contains all the adaptive forms in /content/ folder.

Also is there a way to recover this deleted folder in CRXDE.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `http://<IP>:<port>/system/console/configMgr` location and make sure audit logging enabled.

If its enabled then look at your application default location for `audit.log` file name or else `/var/audit/` location.

Hope it helps.